# jQuery - code working partialy when changing Select, why?

Tags: jquery

I have this in html code:

```
<select name="t" id="t">
<option value="6">test2</option>
<option value="0">Overall</option></select>

<select name="m" id="m">
<option value="9">something to change</option>
<option value="0">back to Overall</option></select>

<div id="main"></div>
```

I would like change automatically Select "t" to Value "0" when user change Value of Select "m" to "0". So I have a jQuery script:

```
$(function(){
  $('#m, #t').change(function(){
      if($('#m').val() == '0') {
      $('#t').val('0').change();
      $("<div>succes!</div>").appendTo("div#main"); }        
  });
});
```

But this script working only partialy. Script doesn't display the information "succes!" after changing Select. Why?

Also you can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQvua/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `.change()` part from this:

```
$('#t').val('0').change();
```

There's no "change" plugin so as it stands it results in a runtime error and the rest of the code does not get executed.

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQvua/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('#m, #t').change(function(){
      if($('#m').val() == '0') {
      $('#t').val('0');
      $("<div>succes!</div>").appendTo("div#main"); }        
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you made some recursion.

Check the console when changing the second selectbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/SQvua/2/